# c# dll not binding/loading

Tags: c#, deployment

I have a DLL which was distributed with my IIS application, it's now suddenly not loading on te live server. When I restart the server the DLL loads correctly and all is fine. After a time of inactivity (possibly timeout or garbage collection cleanup) the DLL is no longer 'found' yet it's still in the same place and nothing has changed.

Looking at the assembly binder log (fuscion log viewer) it would seem that it's no longer trying to load the DLL from the /bin directory but now from the main directory itself.

Two main questions:

1) What could have caused the system to want to load it from the main path

2) Why doesn't it even try and load from /bin.

I'm attaching the log file below.

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (27/05/2014 @ 11:27:53) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicK   eyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/MyProject/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Program Files\MyProject\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f05ee030
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f05ee030
LOG: AppName = 576b7a99
Calling assembly : MyProject, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b281b283028a3f6b.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files\MyProject\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/MyProject/Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: how are you using the DLL in your application? if you deploy your assemblies (DLLs) in the \bin folder, all should be fine or if you want, you can register the DLL in the GAC.

Comment: I basically added the dlls I needed to project references and set 'copytolocal' to true. I can't register or install any thing in GAC as the DLLs (and their versions) used by my application have to be restricted to my directory only (business rule).

Comment: well it should be fine if you added the DLL via project references and deployed with your application. Makes me wonder if you have anti virus software on the server (you shouldn't!) which may cause this to happen when it is loading the assembly. If it works fine locally then no reason why it shouldn't work fine on the server itself. it is 99% likely a server configuration issue somewhere. Is there a reason why you are using Program Files as the folder to deploy on for your website?! really should be inetpub\wwwroot or another root folder on the drive with the right permissions

Comment: There is no antivirus and no 3rd party interference. I'm the only one with access to it as of now. Also the file is still there it hasn't moved it's just that IIS app was looking in the /bin folder before now it's not. As for the file location, My app is 'installed' onto the server as using an MSI installer process.

Comment: normally the installation for a web based project would be in the inetpub folder... if I were you, I would try to move it in the inetpub folder and see if that works, since it would have the right permissions for web apps than any other directory on the system.